# SafetyNet Attestation fails basic integrity in android firebase phoneAuthProvider while using emulators

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

my app worked pretty well on real devices , but when I tried running it on android studio emulators , it crashed every time while trying to login using the phone auth of firebase.
I know it should open a recapcha on the browser , but I didn't see it happening.
I also added the dependency of

```
implementation("androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0")
```

the firebase dependencies are :

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.1.0' 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:7.2.0'
```

the code where it crashes :

```
PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
```

the error log:

[image]

the error log(text) :

```
E/zzbf: SafetyNet Attestation fails basic integrity.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.levins.junky, PID: 18626
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:116)
        at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(LocalBroadcastManager.java:107)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzax.zzh(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.3:1)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzax.zzg(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.3:1)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzf.zze(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.3:6)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzf.zzd(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzb.onSuccess(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.3:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I also checked the Google cloud console oauth2 credentials for the sha1 codes.
I hope someone know this problem , I am working on it more than a week :(

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: the error happens at :
PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)

Comment: Show us the entire error, and not as an image, but as text.

Comment: I added the logs with text.

Comment: Please share more lines of code related to that code, where you're using the context.

Comment: thanks  very much @AlexMamo ! your question made me check the context of the activity , inside 
options.setActivity(activity) , and a small change inside the source of it brought the change. I will publish the solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

big thanks to @AlexMamo , I found out the solution .
it's the activity context inside options.setActiviy(activity) :

```
val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(Firebase.auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(phone)
            .setTimeout(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(activity)
            .setCallbacks(object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                override fun onCodeSent(...
```

the context came from a clickListener inside the login activity . and there I called the function of the authentication . I guess the only place were firebase needs this context is when it use the recaptcha and that's why I haven't seen any problem with it with physical devices till now.
originally the call was this :

```
loginViewModel.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneEditText?.text.toString(),activity=LoginActivity() )
```

and after fix was this :

```
loginViewModel.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneEditText?.text.toString(),this@LoginActivity)
```